# MySQL find NON-matching values in 2 columns of different tables (in different DBs) with one efficient query

Tags: mysql

I have to update col_Foo and col_Bar in table B with the data in col_Foo and col_Bar in table A. The 2 tables have the same primary index id.
This need to be as efficient as possible, as unfortunately I'm compelled to poll the database very ofter and cannot rely on any event system.

This was my first attempt, which doesn't work but I think it makes it easy to understand what I'd like to achieve:

```
select B.*, A.foo, B.foo, A.bar, B.bar
from DB2.B-name as B
inner join DB1.A-name as A
on B.id = A.id 
and (A.bar <> B.bar or A.foo <> B.foo)
```

The following does work, but I wonder if it **could be made more efficient**.
Or if maybe I'm better off just updating the whole column without checking for any mismatch.

```
SELECT A.id, A.foo, B.foo, A.bar, B.bar
FROM DB1.A-name AS A
WHERE A.id NOT IN (
  (
    SELECT A.id as idt
    FROM DB1.A-name AS A
    INNER JOIN DB2.B-name AS B
    ON B.id = A.id
    AND B.foo = A.foo
  )
  UNION ALL
  (
    SELECT A.id as idt
    FROM DB1.A-name AS A
    INNER JOIN DB2.B-name AS B
    ON B.id = A.id
    AND B.bar = A.bar
  ) t
  GROUP BY idt
  HAVING COUNT (*) = 2
)
```

EDIT: adding UPDATE version:

```
UPDATE DB2.B-name AS B
INNER JOIN DB1.A-name AS A
ON B.id = A.id
SET
  B.foo = A.foo, 
  B.bar = A.bar 
WHERE A.id NOT IN (
  (
    SELECT A.id as idt
    FROM DB1.A-name AS A
    INNER JOIN DB2.B-name AS B
    ON B.id = A.id
    AND B.foo = A.foo
  )
  UNION ALL
  (
    SELECT A.id as idt
    FROM DB1.A-name AS A
    INNER JOIN DB2.B-name AS B
    ON B.id = A.id
    AND B.bar = A.bar
  ) t
  GROUP BY idt
  HAVING COUNT (*) = 2
)
```

Comment: *and (A.bar <> B.bar or A.foo <> B.foo)* This check is excess in most cases. MySQL always checks does the updated value is equal to initial one, and the tablebody/indices posessed on disk are updated only when the value is altered. Additionally, this is the reason for do not use auto-utilized columns (updated_at).

Comment: *This was my first attempt, which doesn't work* It contains syntax error - the tablenames contains a dash `-` hence these names must be quoted.

Comment: @Akina those aren't the actual names. And I did use quotes. The query runs without errors but produces all records, so the AND() clause doesn't work. WHERE() doesn't work either.

Comment: /This check is excess in most cases./ I'm trying to get a list of the records that differ in those columns. Have a look at the working query.